# How to use border-radius property with border-image to curve the corners.?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to curve the corners of the image inside the frame but I am unable to do it. I am using basic border-image property and using border-radius property to curve the corners. I do not know what I am doing wrong here. Please check the syntax:

```
<img src="http://blog.queensland.com/files/2013/08/Damien-Leze_WIDE_ANGLE_1.jpg"   class="frame">
```

and CSS code is:

```
img.frame{
border-image: url('http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/het-ionen-frame-van-het-water- 55454.jpg') 80 80 82 84 repeat repeat;
border-width: 60px;
height: 300px; width: 500px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set **overflow:hidden** to your frame.
And add **border-radius** to your image. That's it

Comment: Oh yeah, Thanks. I am new for this and it hard to understand most of the properties. Do you have any suggestion for a beginner like me?

Comment: Just play and enjoy by creating your own sample website/applications.

Comment: @GauravPandey if this is the answer of your choice, then please select this as the correct answer!

Comment: Yeah, it worked for the left half, now trying to solve it for right side. I hope I can make it work soon. What are the best resources to learn it?

Comment: There were many sources in internet to learn any technology. Just keep practicing while learning. That's it.

Comment: @GauravPandey This may help you to learn CSS - [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Target the `img` that is inside your div. For instance

```
<div class="container">
     <img src="imageurl.jpg" />
</div>
```

You can round the corners of the image with

```
.container img{
border-radius:5px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnqu6ejg/)

Comment: I think it will not work. Actually, I am using border-image property and I want to use border-radius with it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but it is not working.

<div><img src="http://blog.queensland.com/files/2013/08/Damien-Leze_WIDE_ANGLE_1.jpg"></div>

And CSS code is:

img{
border-image: url('http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/het-ionen-frame-van-het-water-55454.jpg') 80 80 82 84 repeat repeat;
  border-width: 60px;
  height: 300px; width: 500px; 
}
div{border-radius:10px;
overflow: hidden;}

Comment: It's not working because you want to round the container, but the same effect can be obtained if you just target the image that is in the container, as I did in my Fiddle ;)

If you just want to round the container, then the above answer is the solution.